# probability density function and cumulative distribution function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The Probability density function of a continuous random variable X is given by

$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
cx^2 & 0≤x <1\\
c & 1≤x<2\\
c(3-x) & 2≤x<3\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

There is three parts to this question.

(a) Find c.
Which I found to be$$c= 6/11$$
(b)Calculate the cumulative distribution function F(x) of the random variable X.

(c) Calculate the expected value E(X) and the variance V(X)

I am having troubling finding the cumulative distribution function . 
Which is limiting me to only finding the answer to a.

Thank you ahead of time for the hints and answers.

Comment: What do you know about discrete rvs?

Comment: Yeah. I learned it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution for your first question

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case for you second question